# Django Beanstalk connection refused Error 502 no module named application

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ive been going back and forth with this. Like many in this context, I followed this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html). It worked when creating a skeleton django app but when applied to my existing local app, Im getting this error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'`

**platform:** Python 3.9 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023

this is my working directory

```
pytrade    .(Project Directory)
├── .ebextensions
│   └── django.config
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│   ├── config.yml
│  
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── api (created app)
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── dataMethods
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── questrade_api
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── pytrade
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── requirements.txt
```

wsgi.py

```
    """
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pytrade.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebTestDjango.wsgi:application
```

The WSGIpath is pointing to the right directory and file as far as I can tell.

Comment: Indentation in `django.config` is incorrect. So probably that's why it does not work.

Comment: @Marcin it was just bad pasting and formatting on my part. indentation is fine in file, I modified it in the post